# Does Eclipse store all workspace files somewhere else?

Tags: eclipse

I'm often surprised that Eclipse is giving error during search "File is out of sync with file system", for the file that I have not even opened. I have a large workspace with hundreds of files under SVN control. I have configured Eclipse to "auto-refresh" on load to minimize such issues.
I can't stop wondering how can this happen at all? Why does it need to "refresh" if it should (at least I expect it to) just load everything from file system?

It looks like it's storing all the files somewhere (not even in memory, having a need to refresh on load), and if it's true - I don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does not store your files anywhere except your workspace directory and does not use the file system directly every time when you need some files.

Eclipse indexes/caches different meta-information for all projects and theirs files in your workspace. The information can be found under *.metadata* folder of your workspace directory.

Such information is used to provide the tree of the files to the Eclipse and show resources in views such as Project Explorer, Package Explorer etc.

The main reason of such behaviour is performance purposes.

The out of sync problem appears when:

- you create files manually (out of the Eclipse) in your workspace
- Eclipse plugins or processes create/update/delete/etc. files improperly i.e. do not call related Eclipse API to refresh the resources and update the indexes.

Comment: you can also have a Version Control System, managed outside Eclipse, to modify local files. This happens if you manage VCS outside Eclipse, (e.g. you resynchronize files with server repository). Actually, for eclipse, this is the same as case described by Juna, in which you modify manually a file.  Can this be your case, Kurtevich?

Comment: @grazianogovernatori - yes, this is my case, that's why I was mentioning SVN. It was clear to me that the cause is in the outer changes, but I was confused by the fact that Eclipse even notices such. BTW I'm still not convinced that "performance purposes" are worth getting search errors and needing to do refreshes... but if that's the design...